# Creating a legend and plot multiple data sets in one graph

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib, legend

I am biologist learning python and I have a code that I use that processes my data. However I have a problem making one graph which contains all data sets and legend which is not on top of the graph. I have vast amount of data and the code at the moment plot one at a time which is not very good if I need to compare them. Can anybody help me and give a suggestion what I should do in order to be able to plot one graph with all data on it with legend that is outside of the graph. This is the part of the code:

```
def plotcorrected(self, conditions= 'all', strains= 'all'):
        '''
        Plots the corrected fluorescence per cell for all strains in all conditions.
        '''
        S, t= self.d, self.t
        if conditions == 'all':
            cons= S.keys()
            if 'media' in cons:
                cons.pop(cons.index('media'))
        else:
            cons= gu.makelist(conditions)
            #draw all plots
        if onefig:
            plt.figure()
        for c in cons:
            if strains == 'all':
                strains=  S[c].keys()
            else:
                strains= gu.makelist(strains)
            for s in strains:
                if not onefig:
                    plt.figure()
                if s != 'null' and s != 'WT':
                    #plt.figure()
                    plt.plot(t, S[c][s]['mg'], '.-')
                    plt.plot(t, S[c][s]['mg']+S[c][s]['sg'], 'k:', alpha=0.4)
                    plt.plot(t, S[c][s]['mg']-S[c][s]['sg'], 'k:', alpha=0.4)
                if not onefig:
                    plt.xlabel('time (hours)')
                    plt.ylabel('corrected fluorescence')
                    plt.title('corrected ' + s + ' in ' + c)
                    plt.show()
        if onefig:
                    plt.xlabel('time (hours)')
                    plt.ylabel('corrected fluorescence')
                    plt.title('corrected ' + s + ' in ' + c)
                    plt.show()
```

Comment: I'm tagging this as a `matplotlib` question; please correct the tags if this is incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

To draw all the lines in one figure, call `plt.figure()` (or `plt.subplots()`) only once, since each call creates a new figure. Currently (when `onefig` is `True`) you have a call to `plt.figure()` inside of a `for-loop`, which is why you are getting multiple figures instead of all the lines on one figure.

To move the legend outside the figure's drawing area, you could use

```
leg = ax.legend(loc=2, bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1.0))
```

which places the legend near the upper right-hand corner.

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.02)
y1 = np.sin(2*np.pi*x)
y2 = np.exp(-x)
ax.plot(x, y1, 'rs-', label='Line 1')
ax.plot(x, y2, 'go', label='Line 2')

y3 = np.sin(4*np.pi*x)
y4 = np.exp(-2*x)
ax.plot(x, y3, 'yd-', label='Line 3')
ax.plot(x, y4, 'k^', label='Line 4')

leg = ax.legend(loc=2, bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1.0))
plt.savefig('/tmp/test.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image]

`bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1.0)` anchors the legend to a point outside the figure
in the upper right corner.

`loc=2` [anchors the upper left corner](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#legend-location) of the legend to the location (1.05, 1.0)

Thanks to DSM for showing how to move the legend, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13673982/190597).
More information on how to place and configure the legend can be found in [the Legend Guide](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html).